# simplify pandas dataframe after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll dataframe as result of groupby operation:

```
region  year  
1.0     2015.0    6.775457e+05
        2016.0    6.819761e+05
        2017.0    6.864065e+05
```

How can I convert it into the foll:

```
region  year      val
1.0     2015.0    6.775457e+05
1.0     2016.0    6.819761e+05
1.0     2017.0    6.864065e+05
```

I tried using unstack() but that does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby(['region', 'year'])['val'].sum().reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
   region    year       val
0     1.0  2015.0  677545.7
1     1.0  2016.0  681976.1
2     1.0  2017.0  686406.5
```

Or if aggregate by `sum`, `mean` add parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df = df.groupby(['region', 'year'], as_index=False)['val'].sum()
print (df)
   region    year       val
0     1.0  2015.0  677545.7
1     1.0  2016.0  681976.1
2     1.0  2017.0  686406.5
```

Comment: Glad can help ;)